# Getting Invalid or unexpected token error

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I'm following a YouTube tutorial and I have copied the code, but I keep getting this error. The guy in the video is using Firefox but I decided to use chrome.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time

    class InstagramBot:
        def __init__(self, username, password):
            self.username = username
            self.password = password
            self.driver =webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Ruby/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

def CloseBrowser(self):
    self.driver.close()

def login(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
    time.sleep(5)
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']")
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
    user_name_elem.clear()
    user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
    password_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    password_elem.clear()
    password_elem.send_keys(self.password)
    password_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(5)

def like_photo(self, hashtag):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
    time.sleep(5)
    for i in range(1, 3):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(@, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(5)

    hrefs = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    pic_href = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in hrefs]
    pic_href = [href for href in pic_href if hashtag in href]
    print(hashtag + ' photos: ' +str(len(pic_href)))

    myIg = InstagramBot("that_dominant_male_3.0", "Chhs1905")
    myIg.login()
    myIg.like_photo('newyork')
```

I get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>     (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Try to update your chromedriver, as per docs, ChromeDriver 2.38 supports Chrome v65-67, and you are using Chrome v71, If you still face the issue, then share full trace showing which line of code is causing the error.

Comment: Possibly chromedriver and Chrome browser version compatibility issue.

Comment: @kamal i figured it out. i placed an @ where a 0 should go but thanks for the help. i also did update chrome and chrome driver